# Ruby on Rails: Find the record with lowest value of a specific column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to find a record in the database that has the lowest value of its datetime column. In simpler words, I want to find a record with the earliest time.

I can use minimum to find the lowest value, but that will only return the value itself, and not the whole record.

I suppose I could create another query, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will work:

```
earliest = Model.first(:order => 'column asc')
```

—Where *Model* is the name of your model class and *column* is the name of the datetime column. It will generate this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `Model` ORDER BY column asc LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I know this is pretty late, but isnt it moot using both `.first` and `'asc'` inside the argument hash to `:order`

Comment: @AnkitSoni Without the `first` the query would return multiple records.

Answer (score 3):

```
Table.first(:order => 'created_on')
```

Answer (score 3):

@Ravenstine As of rails 3, the following is proper syntax

```
earliest = Model.order('column asc').first
```

Comment: In 2016 (rails 4 at least) this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about RoR, but with SQL you can just sort the results of your query by the datetime field and limit the number of results to 1.

SQL:

```
SELECT field1,field2,... FROM table ORDER BY datefield LIMIT 1;
```

Or maybe in Ruby (not sure though):

```
table.find(:all, :limit => 1, :order => 'datefield.asc')
```